# Create task in bitrix

Tags: php, curl, bitrix

I need to create task in bitrix from my website form. When a user submit form from my website Client needs to create it as a task in bitrix and automatically assigned to user.

Comment: Your site on hosting that providing create and run php files?

Comment: Yes @ Nikolaj  Sarry

Answer (score 2):

You can use incoming webhook.
To create a webhook, go to Applications > Webhooks.

Click the Add webhook button in the upper right corner and select Inbound webhook.
In the form that opens, fill in the fields:

- Title and Description - arbitrary data.
- Access rights - indicate
  which modules the webhook should have access to.

After saving, a code for webhook authorization will appear.

Together with the code, a sample URL will be presented, which must be used when sending data from a third-party system to Bitrix24: https://********.bitrix24.ru/rest/1/83te1pjdphsa9u15/task/

Where:

- ******** - the name of your portal;
- /rest/ - indication to the system that this address belongs to webhooks;
- /1/ - identifier of the user who created the webhook. This webhook will work under the rights of this user.
- /83te1pjdphsa9u15/ - secret code;
- /tasks.task.add is the REST method that you want to execute when accessing a web hook. The developer must choose the method from the REST API himself, depending on the goals of creating a webhook. [Documentation with REST API task methods](https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/tasks/task/item/index.php)

Use curl(for example) into code of your website.

Answer (score 0):

Use special solution "task from email".
https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/mcart.taskfromemailce/